# Method that returns EnumMap from an Enum passed to it

Tags: java, methods, enums, enumeration

Is this possible? I don't think it is but I just want to make sure.
This is what I was trying.

```
private Map enumToMap(Enum<?> e){
    EnumMap map = new EnumMap<e, String>(e.getClass()); // error can't resolve constructor for EnumMap
    for (History h : History.values()) {
        map.put(h, h.answer());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: You're passing the method parameter as Enum<?>, but inside the method you refer to the type History in a hard-coded way. What's the point of this?

Comment: If you are hardcoding `History`, then you don't need the first enum at all.  If not, then what do you want to do instead of `answer()` for other enum types?

Comment: is `History` an Enum ? How is the arg `e` related to `History` ?

Comment: What's the upvote for? It's not even clear what's being asked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I meant Map, my bad.
Ray, I forgot to edit that part.
History is an enum.
Louis Wasserman, I don't follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `History` is an `enum`. Otherwise you will have a bound-type error.

If the `History` type is an `enum`, then the root of your problem is in the [public EnumMap (Class< K > keyType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#EnumMap%28java.lang.Class%29) constructor, because as per javadoc, it:

> Creates an empty enum map with the specified key type.

In your case, you're defining that the key type will be `History` and in the meantime you're passing an `Enum.class` to the constructor.

A valid definition would be:

```
new EnumMap<History, String>(History.class);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that's how to do it, but I was wondering if I can make it generic (ie make an EnumSet out of any Enum passed to the method).